# Eclipse code style formatter: How to keep closing braces of initializer list in seperate line?

Tags: eclipse, initializer-list, curly-braces

I have set up my own profile in the code style formatter in Eclipse. I have set all brace positions to "Next line", plus in Line Wrapping - Expressions - Initializer list "Wrap all elements, every element on a new line" and have checked "Force split...". Yet, the code appears like this:

```
/*
 * Initializer list
 */
int array[] =
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17 };
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
/*
 * Initializer list
 */
int array[] =
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17 
};
```

Checking "Never join already wrapped lines" helps keep the braces in separate lines only if I manually change it after applying the code style to my code. This is really annoying and costs a lot of time (huge code).

Is there any way to keep the closing braces on separate lines in the default settings?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`.

Click on **Edit** button for the active formatter. A Dialog will appear.

Go to **New Lines** tab. Go to **Array Initializers** group.

Select **Insert new line after opening brace of array initializer** and  **Insert new line before closing brace of array initializer** option save the profile.

Comment: I have C code, so it is the C/C++ codestyle formatter. Under **New Lines** there's only one option: **Insert new line before colon in constructor initializer list**.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I figured I would answer it anyway in the event it helps someone still trying to figure this out.

For some reason a lot of the options that you can change are not visible in the formatter dialog for C/C++ or maybe they are just hard for me to find, like the insert new line before the ending bracket above.

But if you export your formatting to an xml file, you will find that the above options in fact exist and can be hand modified.

To export, click on the "Edit" button for whatever profile you are trying to add this to, you can then export it as any name you like from that dialog.

Once it is exported, you can edit the xml with whatever editor you like.

The lines you want to find and change are:

**"org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"**

**"org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"**

The latter being the one I could not find in the fomatter dialog to save my life for C/C++.

You then save the changes and import back into Eclipse from the same format profile selection dialog (Windows->Preferences->C/C++->Code Style->Formatter).

Also something to note, on some Eclipse-based IDEs (TI's Code Composer Studio for instance), you will have to click the "Show advanced settings" link at the bottom left of the Preferences dialog in order to even see the C/C++ Preference options.

Hope this helps someone.